Как поменять горизонтальный выпадающий список на вертикальный?



body {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  /* background-image: url('../img/1.jpg'); */
  /* background-position: ; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* header */

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  font-size: medium;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.navbar .container {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu__list {
  display: flex;
}

.zemle {
  display: flex;
}

.zemle li {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-menu__list {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-menu div {
  background: #ff000000;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
  background: #135200;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px -5px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  left: 1px;
}

.callback {
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333333ab;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 5px;
}
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="../work/img/logo.jfif" class="navbar-brand">
    <div class="navbar-wrap">
      <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../work/index.html" class="home">Головна</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="zemle1">
            <a href="#" class="zemle1__link">Землевпорядні роботи</a>
            <ul class="zemle1__list-wrapper">
              <div class="zemle1__list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <li>
              <div class="geodez">
                <a href="#" class="geodez__link">Геодезичні роботи</a>
                <ul class="geodez__list-wrapper">
                  <div class="geodez__list">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                </ul>



                <li>
                  <a href="html about__us/about__us.html" class="about-us">Про нас</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="contacts">Контакти</a>
                </li>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="callback">Зворотній зв'язок</a>

</nav>




Добавьте css, пожалуйста

добавил. Буду очень рад если поможете

Пример


.navbar .container,
.navbar-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .container {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.navbar-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-menu a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="../work/img/logo.jfif" class="navbar-brand">
    <div class="navbar-wrap">
      <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../work/index.html" class="home">Головна</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="zemle1__link">Землевпорядні роботи</a>
          <ul class="zemle1__list-wrapper">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="geodez__link">Геодезичні роботи</a>
          <ul class="geodez__list-wrapper">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">"что-то написано"</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="html about__us/about__us.html" class="about-us">Про нас</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="contacts">Контакти</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="callback">Зворотній зв'язок</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>






* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header_sticky {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.header_sticky ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header_sticky ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.header_sticky ul li a {
  color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header_sticky ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.header_sticky ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
<header class="header_sticky">
  <svg width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M21 21L13.3186 8.62439M21 12.9375C18.8012 15.4287 15.5841 17 12 17C8.41592 17 5.19883 15.4287 3 12.9375M3 21L10.6814 8.62439M12 4C10.6193 4 9.5 5.11929 9.5 6.5C9.5 7.39675 9.97215 8.18322 10.6814 8.62439M12 4C13.3807 4 14.5 5.11929 14.5 6.5C14.5 7.39675 14.0279 8.18322 13.3186 8.62439M12 4V3M13.3186 8.62439C12.9358 8.86248 12.484 9 12 9C11.516 9 11.0642 8.86248 10.6814 8.62439" stroke="darkgreen" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path> </g></svg>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Землеустроительные работы</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Геодезические работы</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Что-то написано</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>



Вот пример попроще... без bootstrap. Для компьютерной версии - ок, для мобильной - надо адаптировать.
.header_sticky ul li ul { display: none; } - скрывает список, который будет выпадать при hover
.header_sticky ul li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; } - делает выпадающий список видимым при наведении

Вы ничего не объяснили. Я не понял что и как работает. Из за этого очень сложно подстраивать код под себя. Расскажите пожалуйста как именно вы сделали вертикальный список (скорее всего, это было сделано с помощью js)

@ЯрославЛуговой, Вам не понятен адаптивный пример, созданный при помощи фреймворка bootstrap?

Да. Можно ли как то это сделать без bootstrap? Заранее большое спасибо =)

просто не получается стилизовать хедер
